# How can I write updating class parameter values more concisely?

Tags: python, oop

Simple question; any ideas how to write this more concisely? I have a class with these (already initialised) parameters that I would like to have the option for to update.

```
def update_parameters(self, a=None, g=None, n=None, d=None, s=None, K=None, A=None, L=None):    
    # If the argument is not none, change the parameter value of the class
    if a:
      self.a = a
    if g:
      self.g = g
    if n:
      self.n = n
    if d:
      self.d = d
    if s:
      self.s = s
    if K:
      self.K = K
    if A:
      self.A = A
    if L:
      self.L = L
```

Comment: `self.a = a or self.a`!? What value does `self.a` have before that method is called, is there anything non-`None` stored in it by default?

Comment: yes, the value is initialised when making the class but then this question would have become a bit too long in my opinion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `**args` instead of explicitly defining all of those parameters. You could then use `setattr()` to update any valid ones.

For example:

```py
class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = None
        self.g = None
        self.n = None
        
    def update_parameters(self, **args):    
        for arg, value in args.items():
            if hasattr(self, arg) and value is not None:
                setattr(self, arg, value)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.a}, {self.g}, {self.n}"


t = Test()
t.update_parameters(a=21, z='rubbish', n=100)
t.update_parameters(a=42, n=None)

print(t)
```

This shows `a` and `n` being updated and `z` being ignored:

```
42, None, 100
```

Obviously you need to extend it to all of your parameters.

FYI:

`setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`

Comment: Concise and to the point, thank you!

Comment: I think the condition("if it is not None") is left. Suppose after you updated the instance's namespace with `t.update_parameters(a=42)`, `a` got the value `42`. Then for the second time if you call that method using `t.update_parameters(a=None)`, `a` is gonna be `None` again. OP asked for the opposite.

Comment: Very true, just need to add an extra test `and value is not None`

Comment: @MartinEvans And one more thing. It should be `if value is not None` not `if value`. Otherwise if user passes `0` or any other Falsy values except None, your method refuses it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `**kwargs` and force the users to only pass keyword argument. Then it's easy to iterate over them and use `setattr()`:

```py
class A:
    def update_parameters(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if v is not None:
                setattr(self, k, v)
```

but this has a problem, Any not-none values are going to be added to the instance's dictionary. So maybe you can add another check to see if the `k` is valid.

```py
class A:
    def update_parameters(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k in valid_attrs and v is not None:
                setattr(self, k, v)
```

Or even use the instance's `__dict__`:

```py
    def update_parameters(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k in self.__dict__ and v is not None:
                setattr(self, k, v)
```

Here is the complete code:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

    def update_parameters(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k in self.__dict__ and v is not None:
                setattr(self, k, v)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A(a={self.a}, b={self.b}, c={self.c})"


obj = A(10, 20, 30)
print(obj)
obj.update_parameters(b=40, c=50, d=60)
print(obj)
```

output:

```
A(a=10, b=20, c=30)
A(a=10, b=40, c=50)
```

This ignores the `d=60` value. If you want you can raise exception.

Answer (score -2):

How about making a seperate method that checks for None?

```
def UpdateIfNotNone(To, From):
  if From is not None:  
    To = From
```

Then the original method can be like

```
def  update_parameters(self, a=None, g=None, ...):
  worklist = [(self.a,a), (self.g, g) ...]
  for task in worklist:
    UpdateIfNotNone(task[0], task[1])
```

Comment: This does fundamentally not work because `UpdateIfNotNone` will not update `self.anything`.

Comment: The basic idea is OK, just not implemented correctly. `for task in [('a', a), ...]: if task[1] is not None: setattr(self, task[0], task[1])`.

Comment: oops sorry, thanks for correcting